# Prove the Cartesian product forms an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading a measure theory book, in the Product Measure Chapter the author states the following:

Given two measureable spaces  $(X,\mathcal{A_{1}},\mu_1)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{A_{2}}, \mu_2)$. Let  $C$  be Cartesian product of  $\mathcal{A_{1}}$  and  $\mathcal{A_{2}}$, i.e.

$\mathcal{C} = \{A_1 \times A_2| A_1 \in \mathcal{A_{1}}, A_2 \in \mathcal{A_{2}}\}$

And then he claims: It is obvious to verify that  $\mathcal{C}$  is an algebra on $X \times Y$, without providing any proof.

At first glance I think it quite obvious also, yet after that I failed to prove it.
My attempt is as following: take  $C_1, C_2  \in \mathcal{C}$, which means  $C_1 = A_1 \times A^{'}_1$, $C_2 = A_2 \times A^{'}_2$, where $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{A_1}$, and $A^{'}_1, A^{'}_2 \in \mathcal{A_2}$. So it needs to show that $C_1 \cup C_2 \in \mathcal{C}$. Initially, I supposed  $C_1 \cup C_2 = (A_1 \cup A^{'}_1) \times (A_1 \cup A^{'}_1)$ then the claim is true but it's not the case. So really got stuck on it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is very very false. Which book is this? Are you sure the book makes such a statement?

Comment: @geetha290krm I don't think it's not correct. The book I read is not written in English, so it may be hard for you to read it. Yet the claim is familiar I guess, only I don't know how to prove it. You can find it somewhere, such as the link here: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~beforres/PMath451/Course_Notes/Chapter7.pdf (Lemma 7,1.3, and without proof also).

Comment: What the book says is the class of all finite unions of sets in $\mathcal C$ forms an algebra. It does not say that  $\mathcal C$ is itself an algebra. You should be careful in quoting from books. The way you have quoted the result, you are bringing  a bad name to the author.

Comment: @geetha290krm In the book I mentioned the author did state that $C$ is an algebra, that's why I was so confused. If he claimed that the class of all finite unions of sets in $C$ forms an algebra as in the lecture note above, there would be no confusion. My question is genuine as I've thought about it carefully before posting here. And I didn't bring any information of his name here, so please be kind.  Thanks for your comments anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think there must be a typographical error of some kind in the book, because this is false: if $X_1=X_2= X$ is a set with at least 2 elements, and $\mathcal P(X)$ denotes the power set of $X$, then $\mathcal P(X_i)$ is certainly an algebra, but $\mathcal C = \mathcal P(X_1)\times \mathcal P(X_2)$ is not algebra, because it clearly contains every $1$-element subset of $X_1\times X_2$, and so if it were an algebra it would contain all finite subsets of $X$. But $S\subset X_1\times X_2 \in \mathcal P(X_1)\times \mathcal P(X_2)$ if and only if $S = \pi_1^{-1}(\pi_1(S))\cap \pi_2^{-1}(\pi_2(S))$, where $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are the projection maps from $X_1\times X_2 \to X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively (i.e. they are "boxes"). It is easy to see that most subsets of $X\times X$ do not satisfy this property: if $x_0\neq x_1$ are two distinct elements of $X$, the $S = \{(x_0,x_1),(x_1,x_0)\}$ is an example.

Comment: please see the link I post above, I think the claim is correct itself . I don't really get your point in your example, however. Assume that $X_{1} = \{x_0, x_1\}$, then $\mathcal{P}(X_{1}) = \{\emptyset,\{x_0\},\{x_1\}, \{x_0, x_1\}\}$, $X_{2} = \{x_1, x_0\}$, then $\mathcal{P}(X_{2}) = \{\emptyset,\{x_0\},\{x_1\}, \{x_1, x_0\}\}$. Then for every $C, D \in P(X_1) \times P(X_2)$, the union $C \cup D$ is also in $P(X_1) \times P(X_2)$. Henceforth the set $\{C \times D|C, D \in P(X_1), P(X_2)\}$ is an algebra. So I don't see there is anything wrong here.

Comment: The lecture notes are wrong. The point of the example is that $X_1\times X_2$ has subsets which are not the Cartesian product of a subset of $X_1$ with a subset of $X_2$, the basic example being $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ which is the union of $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. To put it another way, if $\mathcal P(X_1)\times \mathcal P(X_2)$ were an algebra, because it contains all pairs $(0,0),(1,1),(0,1),(1,0)\}$ it would have to contain all subsets of $X_1\times X_2$. But $\mathcal P(X_1)\times \mathcal P(X_2)$ has $1+(2^2-1)^2=10$ subsets while $\mathcal P(X_1\times X_2)$ contains 16.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so there might be some typos somewhere. But the thing is the author used the false claim in order to subsequently construct the product measure based on the algebra $C$ (in fact it is not). That's why I've been so confused. 

After reading through other books (example, A Course in Real Analysis (J. MC Donald, N. Weiss)) I found out that
we only need to show $C$ is just a semi algebra, which suffices to construct the product measure.